# How do I create an angular 2 component that has it's own pipe filter

Tags: angular

I have a component that has it's own data which I want to filter in the template using ngFor and a pipe. The component will accept a search value it will use to filter with.

**Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'seach-results',
    ...
)}
export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('searchValue') searchValue;
    contacts: any[] = [
        { name: 'John Doe', phone: '123-123-1234' }
    ...
}
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of contacts | phone:searchValue>
    <div class="name">{{item.name}}</div>
    <div class="phone">{{item.phone}}</div>
</div>
```

**Pipe**

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'phone'
})
export class PhonePipe {
    transform(items: any[], args) {
        return items.filter(
            item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        );
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out, is how to get the 'phone' pipe be recognized just inside the component. The only way I can get it to work was if I declared the Phone Pipe in NgModule. Is that the only way to do it? I feel like this should be self contained in the component somehow. It looks like there used to be a 'pipes' description in angular 2 components that has been deprecated, but I can't find anything that explains what you're supposed to do instead. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to restrict the pipe to a specific component is to use a separate `ngModule` for both the pipe and the component and then export just the component so that it can be used in another module. See the Demo below.

#### SearchResultsModule:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    SearchResultsComponent 
  ],
  declarations: [
    SearchResultsComponent,
    PhonePipe
  ]
})
export class SearchResultsModule { }
```

#### AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SearchResultsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent //<-- App Component can use the SearchResultsComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

## [Plunkr Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/KgHCQ4FL8EgQ3XmK1Mi4?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are right. It does have to be in an NgModule. I dont see the harm in leaving it there. Why restrict your pipe to only one component? If you only need it for one component, I just wouldn't use a pipe.

**Answer**
Otherwise you can put your pipe in your component, declare that pipe in the providers array in the same NgModule that you declare the component with, and it should work fine.

Check out this edited Heroes Tour plunkr: https://embed.plnkr.co/gYyZANyZAJGmzaPFLG7n/

Navigate to the dashboard component. Look at that and the main Module. Let me know If I need to explain more. If you really want to contain everything in that component, you can give your component its own @NgModule, but no matter what you do, you'll have to do some expot/import somewhere. Just importing the Pipe in the providers array in your main Module is easiest in my opinion.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

**Edited code**

```
//COMPONENT AND PIPE
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero }        from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'dashboard.component.css' ]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = [];
  x = [];
  phonePipe
  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { 
    this.phonePipe = new PhonePipe();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let test = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'];
    this.x = this.phonePipe.transform(test, 'a');
    console.log(this.x);
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
  }
}


@Pipe({
    name: 'phone'
})
export class PhonePipe {
    transform(items: any[], args) {
        return items.filter( 
            item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        );
    }
}



//MODULE

import './rxjs-extensions';

import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent, PhonePipe }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroService }          from './hero.service';
import { HeroSearchComponent }  from './hero-search.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent
  ],
  providers: [ HeroService, PhonePipe ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```